# How to use paginate to json api data in laravel 7

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I am using laravel 7. I fetched data from api in json format. But now I want to show this data by using laravel paginate() function. But i don't understand how to do this.

This is my controller code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class CoronaUpdate extends Controller
{
    //
    function details()
    {
        $total= Http::get('https://corona.lmao.ninja/all?fbclid=IwAR3xgU0oKn3vYCnTm8wmcFzHS52yNp1USvfaFE7Uh9XTYYYaDws3Cm78e4A')->json();

// I want to show this api data with pagination.

        $country=Http::get('https://corona.lmao.ninja/countries?fbclid=IwAR06TC3M8vREqFaehPcDs8g9bQj-NNGfinX-al7vo-a599mDSyjHJbv7hJQ')->json();


        $now = \Carbon\Carbon::now('Asia/Dhaka')->subDay()->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');

        return view('corona',['t_data'=>$total,'c_data'=>$country,'time'=>$now]);
    }
}
```

This is route code:

```
Route::get('','CoronaUpdate@details');
```

This is blade.php:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 heading"> 
            <h1 class="text-center">Country Wise Details</h1>
            <hr>
        </div>      

        @foreach($c_data as $info)
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card mb-4" style="max-width: 25rem;">               
          <img class="card-img-top" height="200px" alt="{{$info['country']}} image" src="{{$info['countryInfo']['flag']}}">     
              <div class="card-body" style="background-color: lightgrey;">
                <h3 class="card-title text-center"><b>{{$info['country']}}</b></h3>

                <h5 class="card-text text-center">Total Case: {{$info['cases']}}</h5>
                <h5 class="card-text text-center">New Case: {{$info['todayCases']}}</h5>
                <h5 class="card-text text-center">Total Death: {{$info['deaths']}}</h5>
                <h5 class="card-text text-center">Today Death: {{$info['todayDeaths']}}</h5>
                <h5 class="card-text text-center">Recovered: {{$info['recovered']}}</h5>
                <h5 class="card-text text-center">Active: {{$info['active']}}</h5>
              </div>
        </div>  
        </div>
        @endforeach



    </div>  
</div>
```

Give me some idea how I do that.

Thanks

Comment: What does `$country` return for you? Is there anything in that response that says `links` or `meta` to indicate that it's returning paginated data? Or is it returning a huge json object?

Comment: return a huge json object. I already show json data in blade.php. but that show all data in one page.

Comment: You could try working with a [Resource Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources#resource-collections) but I'm not totally sure how that'll work. In the docs it mostly uses collections from internal API calls -- data that is requested from your own database, not from a 3rd party.